# Unable to redeploy war-file in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, war

I have a Tomcat v8.5 and a small webservice which I exported out of my eclipse project as a .war file into my tomcat/webapps folder. This works totally fine, though when I try to redeploy the .war, while the server is running, it tries to delete the current deployed version of my webservice. And in this process it fails deleting it completely because it is unable to delete my .log and log.lck file. As expected it is also not possible to delete them manually because they are apparently still in use.

I already tried to set the  `antiResourceLocking` `antiJARLocking` attributes in the context.xml of the tomcat server. Unfortunately the problem remained.

Does anyone have an idea what I could do, to redeploy it while the server is still running?

Comment: Do you have an attribute `autoDeploy` set to true in `server.xml`?

Comment: Yes, I do. `<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" deployIgnore=".svn">`